# Reduction from $2$-Partitioning to (simple) pairwise $2$-Partitioning

Tags: reductions, np-hard, partitions, polynomial-time-reductions

I'm currently stuck showing $NP$-hardness of a problem of mine.

An instance of my problem (I call it (simple) pairwise $2$-Partitioning) is given by the following:

> Given a set of tupels $B=\{(b_1,1),\ldots,(b_n,1)\}$, with $b_i\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}$.
> Goal: A partition of $B$ into two subsets $S_1, S_2$ such that each element $b_i$ is exclusively either in $S_1$ or in $S_2$ and $$(\sum_{i\in S_1}b_i)+|S_2|=(\sum_{i\in S_2}b_i)+|S_1|$$

This can be seen in the following way. When $b_i$ is choosen from the pair $(b_i,1)$ to be in $S_1$ the other Element (in this case always $1$) must be in $S_2$.

I assume that this problem is $NP$-hard and that this can be shown by using the "classical" $2$-Partitioning-Problem where the goal is to partition a set $A=\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ (with $a_i\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}$) into subsets $S_1,S_2$ s.t. the sum of these subset equals.

This far I wasn't able to show that the "classical" $2$-Partiting-Problem can be reduced to (simple) pairwise $2$-Partitioning.

---

My first attempt was to model some arbitrary but fixed instance of the $2$-Partitioning Problem with $A=\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ to an instance of (simple) pairwise 2-Partitioning by constructing $B=\{(a_1-1,1),\ldots,(a_n-1,1)\}$ but somehow wasn't able to show that each $YES$-Instance of $A$ also is some $YES$-Instance of $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you took the problem the wrong way, but your idea is good.

Let $A = \{a_1, …, a_n\}$ be an instance of $2$-$\texttt{Partition}$. Let $B = \{(a_1 + 1, 1), …, (a_n+1, 1)\}$. Then $A$ is a positive instance of $2$-$\texttt{Partition}$ if and only if $B$ is a positive instance of $\texttt{Pairwise}$ $2$-$\texttt{Partition}$:

- suppose there exists $I_1\subset \{1, …, n\}$ such that $\sum\limits_{i\in I_1}a_i = \sum\limits_{i\notin I_1}a_i$. Then:
  \begin{align}
  \sum\limits_{i\in I_1}b_i + |\overline{I_1}| & =\sum\limits_{i\in I_1}(a_i +1)+ |\overline{I_1}|\\
  & = \sum\limits_{i\in I_1}a_i + |I_1| + |\overline{I_1}|\\
  & =\sum\limits_{i\notin I_1}a_i + |I_1| + |\overline{I_1}|\\
  & = \sum\limits_{i\notin I_1}b_i + |I_1|
  \end{align}
- the other way is done in the same manner.